# Create a Databricks service principal in your Databricks account

Tags: databricks, databricks-asset-bundle

My team is currently using Databricks personal access token to deploy Databricks Asset Bundle (DAB). We would like to use service principal as a long term solution. I came accross this Databricks link [link](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/service-principals.html#step-5-use-the-databricks-service-principal-to-generate-its-own-databricks-personal-access-tokens) on how to provision a service principal.

What I don't understand in this tutorial is Step 4. In order to create a Databricks personal access token for the Databricks service principal, one needs to use its own personal access token to create one. What happens if the person leaves, will its token still be valid or is it required to create a new Databricks personal access token for the Databricks service principal?

Answer (score 1):

In step 4 the credentials of the administrator executing the command to generate a the personal access token (PAT) for the service principal are used. However, the resulting PAT that will identify the *service principal* not the administrator who created it. It will be valid until/unless its lifetime expires.